# Bootstrap 2 does not push to heroku together with rails project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails project which uses bootstrap 2 downloadable files. I noticed that after a successful push to heroku, the alignment of the page is gone and it was caused by a failure of bootstrap 2 alignment

Is there any way I could get bootstrap to push to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It will be pushed to heroku if it is in your assets folder. If it is already there, try running

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I ran the command but it still doesn't seem to have been pushed to Heroku.